# Using IIPImage server with openseadragon

Tags: openseadragon, iipimage

I have the IIPImage server running and I am trying to display a deepzoom image but fail

This is how I am doing it :

```
var tileSource = 
{
               Image: 
               {
                  xmlns: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008",
                  Url: "http://127.0.0.1/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi? 
                  DeepZoom=E:/DeepZoomFile/10580_12079_1121935_stitch_files/",
                  Format: "jpg",
                  Overlap: "2",
                  TileSize: "256",
                  Size: 
                  {
                     Height: "38290",
                     Width: "17953"
                  }
               }
};
```

And the important line is :

```
Url: "http://127.0.0.1/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi?DeepZoom=E:/DeepZoomFile/10580_12079_1121935_stitch_files/"
```

I am getting errors from the browser that "fail to load tile image"

Any help or example of how should I do it ?
Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you just use the DZI URL as a tile source instead of defining it as an object like this? In other words, `var tileSource = "http://127.0.0.1/fcgi-bin/iipsrv.fcgi?DeepZoom=E:/DeepZoomFile/10580_12079_1121935_stitch.dzi";` (or whatever the name of your DZI file is)?

Answer (score 0):

No . It doesn't work with a suffix of DZI

Comment: Comments should be placed in the comment section! (click "add a comment" below the user's comment you want to reply).